# How to create a blogpost type form with pictures? Keep Getting Error: NameError: name 'blog_post_id' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

Trying to create a blog post type app...as a newbie :( . I want to create a form that allows pictures along with the *Title* and *Text*

I've tried to define `blog_post_id` in many ways. It's the id column in the data base model

View:

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, request, redirect, Blueprint
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
from inspectorblog import db
from inspectorblog.models import BlogPost
from inspectorblog.blog_posts.forms import BlogPostForm
from inspectorblog.blog_posts.picture_handler import add_issue_pic

blog_posts = Blueprint('blog_posts', __name__)

# CREATE


@blog_posts.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_post():

    form = BlogPostForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        if form.picture.data:
            pic = add_issue_pic(form.picture.data, blog_post_id)
            blog_post_id.issue_pic = pic

        blog_post = BlogPost(title=form.title.data,
                             text=form.text.data,
                             user_id=current_user.id
                             )
        db.session.add(blog_post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Blog Post Created')
        return redirect(url_for('core.index'))

    issue_pic = url_for('static', filename='issue_pics/' +
                        blog_post_id.issue_pic)
    return render_template('create_post.html', issue_pic=issue_pic, form=form)


# BLOG POST (VIEW)
@blog_posts.route('/<int:blog_post_id>')
@login_required
def blog_post(blog_post_id):
    blog_post = BlogPost.query.get_or_404(blog_post_id)
    return render_template('blog_post.html', title=blog_post.title,
                           date=blog_post.date, post=blog_post
                           )


# UPDATE
@blog_posts.route('/<int:blog_post_id>/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update(blog_post_id):
    blog_post = BlogPost.query.get_or_404(blog_post_id)

    if blog_post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)

    form = BlogPostForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        blog_post.title = form.title.data
        blog_post.text = form.text.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Blog Post Updated')
        return redirect(url_for('blog_posts.blog_post', blog_post_id=blog_post.id))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.title.data = blog_post.title
        form.text.data = blog_post.text

    return render_template('create_post.html', title='Updating', form=form)


# DELETE
@blog_posts.route('/<int:blog_post_id>/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def delete_post(blog_post_id):

    blog_post = BlogPost.query.get_or_404(blog_post_id)
    if blog_post.author != current_user:
        abort(403)

    db.session.delete(blog_post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Blog Post Deleted')
    return redirect(url_for('core.index'))


Model:

#models.py
from inspectorblog import db,login_manager
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(db.Model,UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    profile_image = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False,default='default_profile.png')
    email = db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True,index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64),unique=True,index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    posts = db.relationship('BlogPost',backref='author',lazy=True)

    def __init__(self,email,username,password):
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Username {self.username}"


class BlogPost(db.Model):

    users = db.relationship(User)

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)

    date = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.utcnow)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140),nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    issue_pic = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False,default='default_profile.png')

    def __init__(self,title,text,user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.user_id = user_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post ID: {self.id} -- Date: {self.date} --- {self.title}"

Picture Handler:

import os
# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image

from flask import url_for, current_app


def add_issue_pic(pic_upload, blog_post_id):
    filename = pic_upload.filename
    # Grab extension type .jpg or .png
    ext_type = filename.split('.')[-1]
    storage_filename = str(blog_post_id) + '.' + ext_type
    filepath = os.path.join(current_app.root_path,
                            'static/issue_pics', storage_filename)

    # Play Around with this size.
    output_size = (200, 200)

    # Open the picture and save it
    pic = Image.open(pic_upload)
    pic.thumbnail(output_size)
    pic.save(filepath)

    return storage_filename
```

I'm hoping the picture to be saved as `storage_filename = str(blog_post_id) + '.' + ext_type`

Comment: Which of these views are buggy ? I just had a look to the create one and I can see that you try to access blog_post_id which is never defined in this view. Moreover, it's a view to create the blog post so it's not possible to get the blog_post_id before create it.  Try to set your picture data after commit the new blog post to get id usin blog_post.id

Comment: Its the blog_posts/views.py file.

Comment: When I asked you which view, I mean view, not the file. Is it the create, update or delete ? Did you do what I suggested ?

Comment: your right.  Its create so I don't have the blog post id.  The post(blog post) must have a picture included so am trying to find another way.  I'm a bit lost to be honest so will probably go back just a blog post and try from there